# Python - Creating a data frame,transpose and merge it to get a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning Python and I have a question related to creating a data frame for every 5 rows, transpose and merge the data frames.

I have a .txt file with the following input. It has thousands of rows and I need to go through each line until the end of the file.

```
Name,Kamath
Age,23
Sex,Male
Company,ACC
Vehicle,Car
Name,Ram
Age,32
Sex,Male
Company,CCA
Vehicle,Bike
Name,Reena
Age,26
Sex,Female
Company,BARC
Vehicle,Cycle
```

I need to get this as my output:

```
Name,Age,Sex,Company,Vehicle
Kamath,23,Male,ACC,Car
Ram,32,Male,CCA,Bike
Reena,26,Female,BARC,Cycle
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to see this post on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should try break it down into smaller problems to solve, include a code sample, and show examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for `DataFrame` and then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter for new index:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Name,Kamath
Age,23
Sex,Male
Company,ACC
Vehicle,Car
Name,Ram
Age,32
Sex,Male
Company,CCA
Vehicle,Bike
Name,Reena
Age,26
Sex,Female
Company,BARC
Vehicle,Cycle"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=['a','b'])
```

---

```
print (df)
          a       b
0      Name  Kamath
1       Age      23
2       Sex    Male
3   Company     ACC
4   Vehicle     Car
5      Name     Ram
6       Age      32
7       Sex    Male
8   Company     CCA
9   Vehicle    Bike
10     Name   Reena
11      Age      26
12      Sex  Female
13  Company    BARC
14  Vehicle   Cycle
```

---

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df.groupby('a').cumcount(),
              columns=df['a'],
              values=df['b'])
print (df)
a Age Company    Name     Sex Vehicle
0  23     ACC  Kamath    Male     Car
1  32     CCA     Ram    Male    Bike
2  26    BARC   Reena  Female   Cycle
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm a beginner learning Python. I haven't received the required output.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a beginner learning Python. I haven't received the required output.

Comment: a                      b
0           Column1                Column2
1     Name                       abc
2     Depth                              1
3     ParentGroup           Admin
4     Type                           Local
5     Computername           Comp1
6     isGroup                        False
7     Name                   xyz
8     Depth                              1
9     ParentGroup           Administrators
10    Type                          Domain
11    Computername           Comp1
12    isGroup                         True

Comment: After the pivot operation, this is how the output looks like                                                                                                      a        ?  Column1    Computername  Depth          \
0      NaN  Column2    Prod-az-file1             1   
1      NaN     None    Prod-az-file1             1   
2      NaN     None    Prod-az-file1             2   
3      NaN     None    Prod-az-file1             2   
4      NaN     None    Prod-az-file1             2   
5      NaN     None    Prod-az-file1             2